# How to recover LaTeX code from pdf

Tags: pdftex, pdf, code, conversion, convert

Recently, my hard drive destructed and I lost my all files with my project paper too. I didn't do it in Overleaf. I installed a LaTeX software and did it here. Unfortunately all are gone with my laptop.  But I have the pdf version of my work from LaTeX.

Is it possible to convert a "LaTeX PDF" to the "LaTeX code" so that I can edit it?
Or is there another way to convert it?

Comment: But as the top comment on that question says, there's not a good way to go from pdf to tex.  But there are ways to get the text out of the pdf.  Math and graphics are much more difficult.

Comment: @ovi, Depending on the kind of destruction information can still be available on HD. However, it's a task for specialists. Perhaps you know somebody who can retrieve it? // What kind of damage happened to your HD?

Comment: @MS-SPO, actually my hard disk doesn't work.  I went to retrieve it but they said it will take more time to fix. quite impossible to fix it within 3days.  but my submission date is within saturday . Total page is more than 56 with equations and figures which is impossible to write it within 2-3 days. contrariwise, I was new user of Latex and bit slow to do.

Comment: @Teepeemm, thanks  man. I think I have to find another way.

Comment: Allegedly [MathPix is now able to convert entire PDF's to TeX or MarkDown](https://twitter.com/dzackgarza/status/1421704217404887041?s=20). It will not get you the correct preambles and styles, but it may save you some time retyping. (Oops, meant to link to more than just a Tweet. Here's MathPix's page on their features: https://mathpix.com/#features )

Comment: @WillieWong, thank you so much. It works fairly. Although it's time consuming.  but something is better than nothing. some equations don't detect properly ( basically lengthy equations) . but satisfied.